# NoneType object has no Attribute 'destroy' bug in Python when using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x

While using Tkinter to create an application, I encountered the an error with the destroy function.
Here is my Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def show():
    global myl
    myl = Label(root,text='Done!!!').pack()

def ref():
    myl.destroy()
    
b1 = Button(root,text='Submit',font=('ariel',16),command = show).pack()
b2 = Button(root,text='Refresh',font=('cambria',16),command=ref).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

and the Error I am getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__       
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\dhrit\OneDrive\Desktop\Dhriti\python\test101.py", line 10, in ref
    myl.destroy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `show()` you have to say:

```
def show():
    global myl
    myl = Label(root,text='Done!!!')
    myl.pack()
```

All your `Label` and other widgets should be "put on the screen", on a separate line.

Why? Because `myl = Label(..).pack()` returns `None`. When you call `destroy()` method or any other methods on `myl`, your saying `myl = Label(..).pack().destroy()` which does not exist. So you have to `pack()` it in a separate line.

Comment: What an odd quirk!  This worked for me too.

Comment: lost a vac to fix this error. Thank you